# jQuery: Adding Style to selected Day in Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, onselect

I try to manipulate the datepicker of jquery, because I want a multiple selection.
Now I Want to change the style of the selected Day, for example make the text in green.
I have no idea, how I can change the style. Are there any possibilities?

THANKS FOR YOU HELP!

Here is my code:

```
$(".testpicker").datepicker({

    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    onSelect: function(test,object){
        console.log(object.id);

        //#####My first tries######//:
        $("#"+object.id).css('color','green');
        $(this).css('background-color','white');
        //###########//

        if(~$.inArray(test,dates))
        {
            console.log(test)
        }
        else
        {
            dates.push(test);
        }
        console.log(dates);
        console.log(object);
        //prevents closing
        $(this).data('datepicker').inline = true;
    },
    onClose: function() {
        $(this).data('datepicker').inline = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the color of the selected date in datepicker use following css on your jsp page:

```
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-state-highlight {
   background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to open your inspector(firebug) and see the class assigned to the selected cell(selected date).

for example the day of today is given the class `.ui-state-highlight`

the date you select is given the class `.ui-state-active`

Comment: Thats right, but how can I access on the selected day? If it would be an element like this "$("#"+object.id).css('color','green');" it would be no Problem, but the day is in a table, it looks like this: <td class=" ui-datepicker-current-day" onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#dp1368440938806',4,2013, this);return false;">
<a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#">14</a>
</td>

Comment: again if you inspect the datepicker html you 'll find that each cell is just <td> with <a> inside it. try put your click event on that <a>